# Glpi fail2ban regex

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I'm using glpi and i want to monitoring the failed login attemtps with fail2ban. The log file is the following:

[image]

I need a regex rule for this log file, if the login attempts are failed and i want to ban the IP's with the fail2ban.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this: `failed login for \w+ from IP (.*)`

now your match group 1 holds the failed IP address. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SaUoDo/1)